# looping through column won't work?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, substring

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  project_counts <- read.table(
          text = "Project        Counts
                 'Old Patient'       4
                 'Old Customer'      2
                 'New Patient'       5
                 'Children'          3", 
          header=T)
```

I'm trying to create a new column called "Subject" that takes the Count column and multiplies it by 2, based on matching a specific substring from the "Project" column. For example, if Project has the substring 'Old' in it i want the subject column for that row to take the Count*2, but if it says 'New' I want it to take the Count*4, but if it says 'Children' I want it to take the Count*5

I started writing a for-loop just to try with the 'Old' substring and this is as far as I got. Doesn't seem to be working...

```
for (i in 1:length(project_counts$Project)) {
   if (grep('Old', project_counts$Project[i])) {
     project_counts$Subject <- project_counts$Counts*2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project <- c('Old Patient',
             'Old Customer',
             'New Patient',
             'Children')

Counts <- c(4, 2, 5, 3)

project_counts <- data.frame(Project, Counts, stringsAsFactors = F)

project_counts$Subject <- ifelse(grepl('Old', project_counts$Project), 
                                 project_counts$Counts * 2,
                                 ifelse(grepl('New', project_counts$Project),
                                        project_counts$Counts * 4,
                                        project_counts$Counts * 5))

project_counts

##        Project Counts Subject
## 1  Old Patient      4       8
## 2 Old Customer      2       4
## 3  New Patient      5      20
## 4     Children      3      15
```

Comment: it worked! and very very clean! I didnt know how to nest ifelse statements, which was my issue. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Behold the ifelse statement. It can be used to check for successive if-else scenarios, and assign the value to the new column 'Subject'.

```
project_counts <-  tibble::tribble(~Project,~Counts,
              'Old Patient',       4,
              'Old Customer',      2,
              'New Patient',       5,
              'Children',          3)

project_counts['Subject'] <- ifelse(substr(project_counts[['Project']],1,3)=='Old',project_counts[['Counts']]*2,ifelse(substr(project_counts[['Project']],1,3)=='New',project_counts[['Counts']]*4,ifelse(substr(project_counts[['Project']],1,8)=='Children',project_counts[['Counts']]*5,0)))
```

Comment: ahh i see i had no idea how to nest ifelse statements..thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is answered, I tried to come up with a more  generalised way . Take a look

```
project_counts <- read.table(
          text = "Project        Counts
                 'Old Patient'       4
                 'Old Customer'      2
                 'New Patient'       5
                 'Children'          3", 
          header=T)


lookup<- c("Old", "New", "Children")
weights<- c(2,4,5)

tt<- sapply(lookup, function(s)grepl(s, x = project_counts$Project) )

Subjects<- weights[apply(tt,1, which)]*project_counts$Counts

project_counts$Subjects<- Subjects

project_counts
```

#

```
       Project Counts Subjects
1  Old Patient      4        8
2 Old Customer      2        4
3  New Patient      5       20
4     Children      3       15
>
```